# Usage of a parameter in trigger's path of Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

My logic app is triggered by MS Forms submission. I wanted to parameterized the URL of the form, because it will differ on various stages (dev, prod).

Here's what I have in the workflow definition:

```json
          "triggers": {
            "When_a_new_response_is_submitted": {
              "splitOn": "@triggerBody()?['value']",
              "type": "ApiConnectionWebhook",
              "inputs": {
                "body": {
                  "eventType": "responseAdded",
                  "notificationUrl": "@{listCallbackUrl()}",
                  "source": "ms-connector"
                },
                "host": {
                  "connection": {
                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['microsoftforms_1']['connectionId']"
                  }
                },
                "path": "@parameters('FormsUri')"
              }
            }
          },
```

The parameter that I would want to use is `FormsUri`. Its value is: `/formapi/api/forms/4OkuN-CcM0CmSsBwc6kezRPsqtVlTDZAvFnsjb6skuRUNEdsdsd1ZDN1dUR0pBWwewewNVJLTi4u/webhooks` (I changed part of the path before pasting it here). Unfortunately, after deployment of the logic app (which succeeds) I get the following error in the Logic App Designer:

[image]

> Operation not found under connector '/subscriptions/MY SUBSCRIPTION ID/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northeurope/managedApis/microsoftforms'

The original value of the "path" in the trigger was: `/formapi/api/forms/@{encodeURIComponent('4OkuN-CcM0CmSsBwc6kezRPsqtVlTDZAvFnsjb6skuRUNEdsdsd1ZDN1dUR0pBWwewewNVJLTi4u')}/webhooks`. The URL was hardcoded.

Is it even possible to parameterize the "path"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to some test, it shows same error in my logic app. The code of my logic app show  as:

[image]

But why not just parameterize the code of the form but not parameterize the whole url of form ? I changed the logic app as below screenshot and it works fine.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I actually started to use a token and was replacing it during the pipeline run, but this solution is much better!